# Uppy XHR-Upload mode with drag-and-drop?

Tags: reactjs, hapi, uppy

I am evaluating React upload frameworks and stumbled upon [Uppy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uppy).

Looking at the docs, I can’t figure out if it is possible to use Uppy with [Drag and Drop](https://uppy.io/examples/dragdrop/) using [XHR Upload](https://uppy.io/examples/xhrupload/) mode?

Anyone has tried that? I am hoping to use an existing [hapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/hapi) backend.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple to use with XHR Upload. There is currently no example for it, but I'm pretty sure that it is possible. Assuming that you are using a Functional Component rather than a class based one, here is some example code

```js
import Uppy from '@uppy/core';
import XHRUpload = from '@uppy/xhr-upload';
import { DragDrop } from '@uppy/react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const uppy = React.useMemo(() => {
    // Do all the configuration here
    return Uppy()
      .use(XHRUpload, {
        endpoint: 'your backend endpoint'
      })
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => uppy.close()
  }, [])

  // Other props are also needed, see https://uppy.io/docs/react/drag-drop/
  return <DragDrop uppy={uppy} />
}
```

That should work just fine. In general, most of these choices in various areas (ex. destination, providers, framework, etc), work well together, minus a few exceptions.

I hope this helped, let me know if this works or if there are any further issues

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see other answer for example,
but here is why you should **not**:

- Uppy's `XHRUpload` does not support *`pause`*, *`resume`* or *`chunk`* to begin with.
- Which is intentional, since `Uppy` want's to encourage you to use TUS.
- Hence use Uppy's TUS mode, or instead use an entire other library, like [`DropZone-JS`](https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone).